# Odd behavior with CLLocationManager when app becomes active again

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager

When I close an iOS app that uses location services (to run in the background) and open it again the CLLocationManager will always call the didUpdateLocations delegate method with the last position it send before the app was closed (or very near to that location). As opposed to send the (possibly) new location the device is at. The correct location will be sent milliseconds after the first wrong position was sent.

I don't see any mentions in the documentation or on web search engines about this behavior. Doing a route-tracking app, this behavior bugs me as there will be a big jump in the route.

Of course one could come up with a simple workaround by ignoring the first location that is sent after the app becomes active but that seems a bit odd to me. I wonder why Apple would do it that way and if there is a better way to oppress the wrong locations.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The given CLLocation object has a timestamp property. When you store the timestamp of the last time the app did became active you can discard all given locations that have a timestamp before that time.

Answer (score 0):

As per [CLLocationManager documentation :](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

> "Because it can take several seconds to return an initial location, the location manager typically delivers the previously cached location data immediately and then delivers more up-to-date location data as it becomes available. Therefore it is always a good idea to check the timestamp of any location object before taking any actions. If both location services are enabled simultaneously, they deliver events using the same set of delegate methods."